# How to widen the Source Insight Location view?

Tags: source-insight

I am using Source Insight to browsing a large code base. When searching for some symbol definitions, the Location view is too narrow to display the full content. Shown below. Anyway to widen it?
[image]

(I was planning to post it to Superuser but unfortunately there's no proper tags.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot do that.

This is one of many annoying defects in Source Insight 3.5 GUI.
In version 4 they fixed some of them but they still have many areas for improvements in user experience.